# How to correctly removeFromSuperview?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Apple says:

> removeFromSuperview Unlinks the
> receiver from its superview and its
> window, and removes it from the
> responder chain.
>
> - (void)removeFromSuperview
>
> Never invoke this method while
> displaying.

So, when I want to get rid of a view, I was used to just kick it off from it's superview. Why should I never invoke that while it's visible? So I must set it to hidden=YES before I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The specification specifies "while displaying" not "while it is on display".  Thus, you should never call `removeFromSuperview` in the view's `drawRect` for example.

`removeFromSuperview` releases the view and may deallocate it.  The parent view when attempting to display the view may not expected it to be deallocated and cause a corrupted access.