# UIViewController remove subview

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I add a view as subview of my uiviewcontroller like this:

```
// into my ViewController:
UIImageView *imView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"]];
imView.frame = CGRectMake(2, 46, 1020, 720);
[self.view addSubview:imView];
```

now, with another button I wish remove the imView from the subview chain..
how can I do to do this??
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call this method, which belongs to UIView (and UIImageView inherits from UIView)

[UIView - (void)removeFromSuperview](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/removeFromSuperview)

Comment: thanks! I tried but the uimage view is still in the viewcontroller...
I looked into your link and is written that 'Never invoke this method while displaying.'....
but i need to remove when displaying...

Comment: Are you sure that is "when displaying" not "when it is on display"? You can take a look at this question, it can answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144496/how-to-correctly-removefromsuperview